# Performance measurement of an event extraction system

Tags: clustering, performance, text, model-evaluations

I have developed an event extraction system from text documents. It first clusters the data corpus and extracts answers for *what, when* and *where* questions. Final answers are determined by using a candidate scoring function. I am struggling at evaluating the performance of the system. What measurements should I consider?  Any suggestion is highly appreciated. An Image explaining the problem is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard evaluation would be to count the proportion of correct predictions.

- The most basic version would be to count 3 instances for every event: where, when, what. For example if the three questions are answered correctly the score for this event is 3/3. Note that the case where one of the questions has no answer should be counted normally, i.e. if the system doesn't give any answer it's correct but it's an error if it does.
- You might also have the case where an event is not detected at all by the system, in this case it makes sense to count as if it has the three questions wrong: 0/3.
- It looks like you can also have several answers for one of the question. In this case you might want to count partial answers, for example 0.5 if the system finds one correct answer out of 2. There can be different variants of this option.

The final evaluation score is simply aggregated across all the events.
Note that it would be common to count the detailed score for each type of question as well.

Comment: I have employed two external annotators to find answers as the ground truth. So it will be basically the accuracy as I understand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage Yes, it's accuracy but in a complex case like this it's important to clarify what is counted as an instance and how the final score is aggregated, since there are several options. Considering alternatives like precision/recall/f1-score is also possible but it would probably be even more complex: it depends if there is clear way to define what is a positive or negative instance, and at first sight it's not clear how in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much.